Movie or TV series about Robbery
I'm trying to recall a a movie or tv series.....
where I watched a team of robbers trying to rob a bank. The only scene that I recall is that one of them used a trick for alibi. They were in a party and that man goes to a stage and shake hands with another person and while shaking hand he tampered the other man wrist watch and make it ahead like one hour or so. In the meantime his partners took photo.
The robbery begins after that and end of it they was caught by the police and show the picture they taken and naturlly the watch showed the time of the robbery and they had a perfect alibi. And also police talk to the witnes,the man wearing the wrist watch.He say they were there at that time. So the police had to let them go.
That all I can remember... Please help me find out the name of that series....

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

This sounds very much like one of the tricks Derren Brown (an English illusionist and mentalist) pulled off.
For this trick, he bet a friend of his (millionaire art collector Ivan Massow) that he could steal a £100,000 painting.  Part of the bet was that Derren would tell Ivan which painting, when it would be stolen, and even provide a photograph of the criminal.
Part of the show revolved around stealing a watch and changing the time.  This wasn't to establish an alibi: it was to confuse the issue (since Ivan knew the time the painting would be stolen).
Part of the pre-theft did involve an unexpected incident with police.
You can catch the entire episode on YouTube.  (Note that there is a lot of build up before the robbery itself.)

Thank you Ghotir but I watched the episode but it was not what I was talking about :( . But It was interesting series thou. Thank you for tying.
